# MySQL find duplicate of a row and put in a field

Tags: mysql

I have this table:
[image]

With this query I'm extracting not activated songs, but **I want to add a value (duplicate) if the song has an activated duplicate**, how can I do it?

```
SELECT 
  libs.song_id,
  songs.name AS song_name,
  artists.id AS artist_id,
  artists.name AS artist_name,
  songs.description,
  libs.status,
  libs.activated,
  libs.giftable,
  IF(CONDITION, 1, 0) AS duplicate
FROM libs, songs, artists
WHERE
  libs.song_id = songs.id &&
  artists.id = songs.artist_id &&
  libs.activated = 0 &&
  libs.user_id = '1'
;
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I expect to get this:

```
song_id|song_name|artist_id|artist_name|description|status|activated|giftable|duplicate
1      | "name"  | "id"    | "name"    | "descr"   | 0    | 0       | 1      | 1  
2      | "name"  | "id"    | "name"    | "descr"   | 1    | 0       | 0      | 0
```

Comment: what is your wished result ?

Comment: @echo_Me Added in question.

Comment: Duplicate of SO MANY Questions, just copy the title and search.....

Comment: @pc-shooter I need to get it into a value...

Comment: Why do you have songs with the same ID??

Comment: @pc-shooter It's a user library table of activated products and not, not activated productes can be gifted.

Comment: Ok I see, Just an idea: two columns as primary key... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206868/two-column-as-a-primary-keys-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
select song_id , artist_id,status,activated,max(duplicate) duplicate from(

SELECT 
song_id,

artist_id,

status,
activated,
giftable,
if(activated = 1,1 ,0) duplicate
FROM Table1
WHERE


artist_id = '1'

)t
group by song_id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bd15/12)

Comment: I need to get not activated items and search if they have activated duplicates for the same user