# Mysql table multiple primary key relation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have table with 2 columns. ID1 and ID2.
I want make 2 columns as primary key.

When insert `ID1=22 , ID2=55` and `ID1=55 , ID2=22` this as same and do not insert and show error!

Note*: This table is a relation ship. Same bro and sis. Really have 3 colmuns: ID1 , ID2 , TYP.

1. ID1 = first user id
2. ID2 = second user id
3. TYP = type of relation ship(bro/sis/uncle/aunt...)

Now how can i set all columns as primary? When ID1 and ID2 as how i explain above and also make TYP primary too? Thanks@>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have an easy way of identifying that (id1, id2) and (id2, id1) should be the same.

So, you would need to create a trigger to handle this.  If `(id1, id2)` is already a primary or unique key, then something like this:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger tr_table_insert before insert on t
for each row 
begin
    if (exists (select 1
                from t
                where t.id2 = new.id1 and t.id1 = new.id2
               )
       ) then
        set msg = concat('Combination ', new.id1, ' and ', new.id2, ' already exists);
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
end;
delimiter $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have primary keys with multiple columns like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14206868/5830574) or in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57573) example.
Simply add `PRIMARY KEY (ID1, ID2)` to your `create table` statement.

What I'm a bit worried about is that you say `(22/55)` and `(55/22)` should be detected as duplicates. With PK on ID1 and ID2 alone that would not be the case. `(22/55)` and `(55/22)` are different, but that's perfectly OK with a table for relationships: If 22 is the aunt of 55, then 55 is the *nephew* of 22, so there *should* be two rows in that table.